# C++ array 'matrix' swap (memory leak)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, stack-overflow

I'm creating a block based engine and I was working on infinite loading. I was testing some code, but soon I noticed some troubles. At first I was using an `std::unordered_map`, storing xz as key and ChunkContainer* as value. I store this as pointers (with new) because it's such a big object it can't be all stored on the stack. It's size is: `CHUNK_SIZE(32)^3 * WORLD_HEIGHT(8 amount of chunks in height) * 4(block bytes) = 1048576 bytes`. (And that * 225 makes up my world.)

Then I swapped to using a big array instead of the `std::unordered_map` so I could achieve faster read speed. So I needed to swap the loading code. I came up with this code,

but I'm having some issues with a memory leak created when using this code:

```
for(int z = 0; z < size; z++){
    temp = loadedChunkContainers[(size-1)*size + z]; //Store the last container in a temp var

    for(int x = size-1; x > 0; x--){
        loadedChunkContainers[x * size + z] = loadedChunkContainers[(x-1) * size + z]; //Move all containers 1 to the right
    }
    int cx = temp.getX() - size;
    int cz = temp.getZ();

    temp.move(cx, cz);//Move the container internally
    loadedChunkContainers[z] = temp; //put the container back into the array, but this time on the first row
    buildQueue.push_back(&loadedChunkContainers[z]);
}
```

`temp` is a global variable because I can't store it locally because it will overflow the stack. I also can't use swap as it will also overflow the stack.

Should I even use this code? It works, but It's quite a slow way in the first place. Would there be another way to have the fastest read access while still being able to swap values (without memory leaks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `std::unordered_map` will never store its elements "on the stack", so this is not a good reason to store pointers. You can basically forget all of your stack-related worries, here. With that goes away all your pointer troubles. Just store the elements directly and be done with it!

If you have measured the `std::unordered_map` version of your code and found that the (very fast) hash lookup is prohibitively slow in your application, by all means stick with your sparse array, but make it a `std::vector` so that elements are dynamically allocated [for you]. Then everything I said in the first paragraph still applies. :)

Comment: Yeah, but then I still have the read access speed issue. As hashmaps are slower then arrays

Comment: @Duckdoom5: That sounds like [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt). Did you measure it and find out that the (very fast) hash lookup was prohibitive in your project? Even if you stick with the sparse array, make it a `std::vector` and then I stand by the advice in my answer.

Comment: Well, actually, now that I think about it. The reason it was slow, was because I used strings as key. (It has been a while since I used the map so I can't remember exactly what made me switch.) I might try again with the `std::unordered_map`. Can you change the key of a value without replacing it? cus that would fix all of the issues immediately

Comment: @Duckdoom5: [Heh, no. :)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6773748/560648) Though Boost.MultiIndex can do it...

Comment: Hmm, okay. And just removing and re-adding the element, would that cost a lot or would the Boost.MultiIndex be much faster?

Comment: @Duckdoom5: I don't see why it would be very expensive. Measure it.

Comment: Could you help me with the stack overflow? I've edited the post.

Comment: @Duckdoom5: That's a new question. Please submit it as such.

Comment: As you wish, I thought I'd ask here because I have to wait 90 mins to create a new post

Comment: @Duckdoom5: There is a reason for that: it is so that you _think_ about your new problem first. It is obviously not there to encourage you to post your question in the wrong place instead.