# Bind const std::pair<T, U>& to value of std::pair<const T, U>

Tags: c++, reference, stl, constants

The below code snippet compiles with a very important warning.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template <typename iterator>
const std::pair<int, float> &foo(iterator it) {
  return *it;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> vector;
  std::map<int, float> map;
  vector.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 0.0));
  map.insert(std::make_pair(0, 0.0));
  const std::pair<int, float> &r1 = foo(vector.begin());
  const std::pair<int, float> &r2 = foo(map.begin());
  if (r1 != r2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There is an implicit conversion from `std::pair<const int, float>` to `std::pair<int, float>` during `foo(map.begin())` that creates a dangling reference.

```
ref2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const std::pair<int, float>& foo(iterator) [with iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, float> >]’:
ref2.cpp:16:52:   required from here
ref2.cpp:7:11: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   return *it;
           ^~
```

We could adjust the type of `r2` to `std::pair<const int, float>` in this case.  Nevertheless, it would be useful, in the general case, to assign the results of the two calls to `foo()` to type-compatible references.  For example, the call to `foo()` might be wrapped in another function that always returns `std::pair<int, float>&`.

Can the reference assignment be made to operatate in a way that works around the misalignment of const modifiers?

Comment: Why not just use `auto`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Functions returning references are a big exception to that rule.

Comment: @hvd Strictly speaking, it's not really an exception. Binding a prvalue to a reference extends the prvalue's lifetime to the lifetime of the reference. So the function first binds the prvalue to a reference inside the function, and then copies that reference out of the function to a second reference in calling scope. But the first reference dies when the function exits, and therefore so does the prvalue, the second reference dangles. But yes, in spirit it is.

Comment: @KerrekSB Inside the function `foo`, depending on the concrete type of `iterator`, either `*it`'s type matches and a reference to it is returned directly, or a temporary is created and initialised from `*it`, and that temporary is bound to the reference that gets returned. "This is not a "dangling reference"" is not right. When a temporary is created (as in the OP's use of it), there certainly is a dangling reference in there, and the compiler is right to warn for it.

Comment: @hvd: Ah, yes, of course. I misread the code. This is indeed bad.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

The question is really about making `std::pair<K,V>` work with `std::pair<const K,V>`; `vector<>` and `map<>` are red-herrings.  (In particular, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773734/force-key-type-of-a-stdmap-not-to-be-const) about why the *key* in `std::map<>` is `const`.)

Better sample code might be:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename iterator>
const std::pair<const int, float>& bar(iterator it)
{
    return *it;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::pair<const int, float>> v1{ std::make_pair(0, 0.0f) };
    bar(v1.begin());

    const std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> v2{ std::make_pair(0, 0.0f) };
    bar(v2.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

---

According to your comments, what you're really trying to figure out is how to make the `std::map<>` iterator work like `std::vector<>`; the result should be a `std::pair<>` in both cases, not `std::pair<const int, ...>`.

With that, I've written this hack; I'm sure it's got problems and/or could be improved:

```
const auto& remove_const(const std::pair<const int, float>& p) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const std::pair<int, float>&>(p); // :-(
}

template <typename iterator>
const std::pair<int, float> &foo(iterator it) {
    return remove_const(*it);
}
```

Comment: You should probably use iterator traits for this.

Comment: I understand the response, but the oriignal question pertains to the possibility of unifying the return type regardless of template parameter, as opposed to making the return type parameter-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You might change:

```
template <typename iterator>
const std::pair<int, float> &foo(iterator it) {
  return *it;
}
```

to:

```
template <typename iterator>
decltype(auto) foo(iterator it) {
  return *it;
}
```

this requires c++14, to stay with c++11 use:

```
auto foo(iterator it) -> decltype(*it) {
```

Comment: Doesn't setting the return type to `auto` simply defer the type incompatibility to the assignment by the caller?  Even if both `r1` and `r2` are also `auto` they will still be different types that need to be converted at the time of comparison, right?

Comment: No, it simply chooses the correct return type for foo - now its always `std::pair<int, float>&`, but it should be : `std::pair<const int, float>&` and `std::pair<int, float>&`

Comment: also to be strict its not `auto`, but `decltype(auto)`, the difference is important if you would choose `auto` then reference would be removed.